# how do you get the name of the Plugin that is executing when an exception occurs?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am sure that I am overlooking something obvious, but how do you get the name of the Plugin that is executing when an exception occurs? (outside of parsing the stack trace)

Comment: Is it not in the stack trace?

Comment: If logic not so comprehensive you can just look in Plugin Registration Tool for all steps(plugins) that register for your entity. In most situations it can reduce range of search, but it does not solve your issue completely.

Comment: I realize there are a couple utilities to find this manually.  However I would like to find the name programmatically for use during runtime execution of my code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew I was just overlooking something:

```
Type tmpType = this.GetType();
_PluginName = tmpType.FullName.ToString();
```

Produces: Your.Namespace.PluginName

What threw me off was the fact that I was looking for something CRM specific.  I was too focused on the CRM SDK and didn’t think to take a step back and look at System.Type.